# locationManager didUpdateLocation, change UIElements on another class swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, viewcontroller

So I implemented location in my app.

I created a class with handles the location stuff, I'm using locationManager didUpdateLocations to know when a location is found. 
What I need to accomplish is to change image on a button and stop a activityIndicator in a another class(viewController).

I tried to get an instance of the viewController to use in my locationClass but it failed and returned nil.

Does anyone have a good way to accomplish this?
I would think i need to get an instance of my viewController, but I failed to do so. BTW the location stuff is working!

Edit:
Thanks to naomimichiko I managed to do it. I added an answer that explains how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to write your own protocol that fires a method call in didUpdateLocations to let your other class know.

Comment: I'm going to try that now. Will give feedback later.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I will update my question to let others know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to naomimichiko I made a protocol that handles what I needed!
Here's how I did it:

I first created a file named: 'protocols.swift'. In this I declared my protocol:

```
@objc protocol LocDelegate{
optional func locationFound()
}
```

In the location class witch handles the location stuff I added:

```
var delegateLoc: LocDelegate?
```

I have the func locationManager didUpdateLocaton In the location class and in there I did this:

```
delegateLoc?.locationFound!()
```

This will then "run" the function if there is a class listening on this.

In my viewController where I need to update the labels and shit I added the protocol to the class like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, LocDelegate
```

Then in viewDidLoad i set the delegate to self.

```
let locatonClass = locationClass()
locatonClass.delegateLoc = self
```

What's left is just to add the func that the protocol needs:

```
func locationFound() {
    self.hereIAm.setImage(UIImage(named: "loc1.png"), forState: .Normal)
    self.activityIndicator1.stopAnimating()
}
```

That's it...It was really simple but so hard to figure out how to accomplish this.
Read more about custom protocols here: [Custom Protocols](http://sledgedev.com/create-custom-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-objective-c/)

Comment: nice! Sorry my answer wasn't super descriptive but sounds like you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `delegate` or `NSNotification` to notify others when location updated.